# How to update external .dll control reference

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dll

I have Class library (`chart control`) which was created in Visual Studio 2005 and I was going to use it in a new project (VS2010).

I clicked on **Choose Items...** from the toolbox, selected .NET componentes and Browse for the `.dll` file. The chart control was normally placed in the toolbox list.

The problem is that I want to modify a specific function from the char control. 
I opened the original project in VS2005 and changed the function as well. 
But now it seems that the VS2010 project cannot identify these changes. 
I've already deleted the control from the toolbox list and reloaded again in the same way but it seems that it loads the old dll again.

It's strange because when I rebuild the chart control project, I see that the `.dll` file in Release path updates its written date. I've tried to copy this `dll` to another path and then load this new `dll` from the VS2010 but still it loads the old version. Already restarted the VS2010 without success.

How is it possible that the VS2005 rebuilds the `.dll` file and the VS2010 still can load the old version of it?

**EDIT:** thanks to @Gilchrist: just updating the control in the toolbox does not update the reference. To solve it I had to remove it from the toolbox, remove the project reference and then add again in the toolbox (which creates the new reference link).

Comment: What do you mean by loading and reloading.  Are you updating the reference in your project?  Look at the solution explorer, under your project, in the references section.  Have you removed and readded the reference to that DLL?

Comment: What I've done was deleting the DLL from the toolbox and going again in Choose Items, Browse and selecting the DLL file. Isn't it enough to reload the file and update its reference?

Comment: If the only thing you did was to delete it from the toolbox and then reload it into the toolbox, then no, that is not enough.  The toolbox is not the link from your project to that dll.  The reference is. You need to remove that reference and recreate it.  I have never tried what you did myself, but I am guessing that when you added the control from your toolbox onto your project, the reference got created, but updating the toolbox is not updating the reference.  I would try removing the reference and then adding it back in.